# Not straight angle in Sumo/Plie squat hinting of inflexibility in groins, hips, back or elsewhere?

Tags: squats, flexibility, hip

I am trying to understand the reason for the angle in plie/sumo squat:

[image]

where I think I get more angle than the girl [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bYgLsspWVcI&t=5m13s).

**What can cause the angle in sumo squat? Is it due to poor hips flexibility and/or groins flexibility?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found plie squat kind of deceiving because watching someone do it from the front makes it looks like their legs are near 180, but every instruction I found online has you put your feet out at 45-degree angles. I'm not sure it's necessary to do more even if you can.

Comment: Yeah that is a good point but I mean the angle in the back (not squared angle between feet). The other is bending down while the other more straight. I cannot do the right one totally like that -- actually excellent point! I did the plie squat with over squared feet in 180 degree that is totally crazy flexibility! Solved!